# How to return median and values for x standard deviations from it in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of data containing numeric values and categories. I'd like to return a new table which gives the median by category and values 1 or 2 standard deviations below it to run some further analysis. I can get the median using the wiki function but as below, but struggling with the standard deviation.

```
SELECT max(d_voa_record1.unadjustedprice) AS max_sqm_rate
    ,min(d_voa_record1.unadjustedprice) AS min_sqm_rate
    ,count(d_voa_record1.unadjustedprice) AS sample_no
    ,max(d_voa_record1.spec_catcode) AS scat_code
    ,avg(d_voa_record1.unadjustedprice) AS avg_rate
    ,median(unadjustedprice)
FROM processed_data.d_voa_record1
GROUP BY d_voa_record1.spec_catcode;
```

I'm running on postgres 9.6

EDIT: As comments solution also provides percentile ranges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the median with the [continuous percentile](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-expressions.html#id-1.5.3.6.15.15.1) function:

```
percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by unadjustedprice) as median
```

And [`stddev_samp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-STATISTICS-TABLE) calculates the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation):

```
percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by unadjustedprice) -
     stddev_samp(unadjustedprice) as one_stddev_below_median
```

Which you can multiply by 2 to get two standard deviations below median:

```
percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by unadjustedprice) -
    2 *  stddev_samp(unadjustedprice) as two_stddev_below_median
```

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for, thank you. Also gives percentile range which would have been my next q.

Comment: For reference to others, any of the above go into the main select statement in my question and ran.