# Postgres 9.5 Function to determine Normal Distribution

Tags: postgresql, statistics, standard-deviation

This questions answers how to find **2 standard deviations** from the **median**:

[How to return median and values for x standard deviations from it in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50352013/how-to-return-median-and-values-for-x-standard-deviations-from-it-in-postgres)

However, it's only really useful if your data has a **normal distribution**. Is there a postgres function (I'm using 9.5) to determine if the data has a normal distribution?

For example, is there something that can caclulate the **Shapiro Wilk** Test described here?

http://www.real-statistics.com/tests-normality-and-symmetry/statistical-tests-normality-symmetry/shapiro-wilk-test/